# What color would these divs be in css given these classes and why?

Tags: css

Given these classes which color would be applied to the first and second div?

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
    
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red blue">Hello</div>
<div class="blue red">World</div>
```

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Are you copy>pasting an exam question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between order you put classes in the HTML, there is a difference in order styles was declared. The `blue` one was declared after the `red` so style was overridden.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) stands for Cascading Style Sheets.

The **Cascading** part means:

> pass (something) on to a succession of others.
>
> The name cascading comes from the specified priority scheme to determine which style rule applies if more than one rule matches a particular element. This cascading priority scheme is predictable.

Basically, this means, that if there are 2 styles of `color` targeting the same element, the last one will be the one that is applied. Which in your example above is `blue`.